# What if $NP\subseteq BPP$?

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm new to complexity and came upon the following exercise which I'm unable to solve.

Prove that if $NP\subseteq BPP$ then $\Sigma_2^p=\Pi_4 ^p$.

Comment: Karp Lipton + Adelman's

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Sipser-Lautemann theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sipser%E2%80%93Lautemann_theorem): $\mathrm{BPP} \subseteq \Sigma_2^p \cap \Pi_2^p$.

Comment: Should query be $\Sigma_2=\Pi_2$?